# Error when fresh install Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, centos7, server-configuration

I installed a new fresh project Laravel 5. It worked on local, but not working on server (CentOS 7, LAMP). I installed the server as required by Laravel:

- PHP >= 5.5.9
- OpenSSL PHP Extension
- PDO PHP Extension
- Mbstring PHP Extension
- Tokenizer PHP Extension
- Mod_rewrite enabled

I executed `CHMOD 777` to *storage* folder. When i run project on browser, nothing displays. Looking in the console tab, it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Content of `error_log` file

> [Mon Jul 27 12:45:20.618306 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1448] SELinux
>   policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
>   [Mon Jul 27 12:45:20.681536 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 1448] AH01232:
>   suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec) AH00558: httpd:
>   Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,
>   using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally
>   to suppress this messa$ [Mon Jul 27 12:45:20.751429 2015]
>   [auth_digest:notice] [pid 1448] AH01757: generating secret for digest
>   authentication ... [Mon Jul 27 12:45:20.753167 2015]
>   [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 1448] AH02282: No slotmem from
>   mod_heartmonitor [Mon Jul 27 12:45:24.458038 2015]
>   [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1448] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
>   PHP/5.6.11 configured -- resuming normal operations [Mon Jul 27
>   12:45:24.458129 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1448] AH00094: Command line:
>   '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND' [Mon Jul 27 12:53:02.593593 2015]
>   [:error] [pid 2558] [client 192.168.56.1:56015] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream
>   or file$ [Mon Jul 27 12:53:02.663948 2015] [:error] [pid 2558] [client
>   192.168.56.1:56015] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file$

Please help me. Thanks!

UPDATE:
I do have a APP_KEY and the APP_DEBUG is also set to true. but im not getting the Views. I just Tried echo a string in the `routes.php` .

`Route::get('/', function () { echo 'test'; return view('welcome'); });`

I can see the word 'test' but not the view..

p/s: All folder in `storage` and  `bootstrap/cache` ar writeable (CHMOD 777)

> DONE: i'm disable SELinux on my server and this problem has been resolved :D
>   Thanks all

Comment: What web server are you using? nginx? apache?

Comment: BTW, 777 is usually frowned upon -- consider tightening that up once you get things working.

Comment: @Ben: i'm using apache

Comment: Your PHP settings appear to be ok. Have you enabled debugging in your Laravel project?

In my case, I opened my .env file in my project root and set ``APP_DEBUG`` to true. You may also want to check your error_reporting settings in your .htaccess or even php ini file.

Answer (score 0):

A few checklist items for you:

1. First, check the log file in storage/logs -- this usually has the answer.
2. Check the apache log file.
3. Make sure any subfolders in `storage` are also writable by the web server.
4. Be sure you've installed the mcrypt extension -- this one always trips me up.
5. Make sure you've run `composer install` to install Laravel's requirements.
6. Make sure to set your app key with `php artisan key:generate`
7. Add `die('test');` to line 1 of public/index.php to verify apache is configured correctly.

Comment: Thank you Ben, i'm sure any subfolders in storege ar also writeable by the webserver. However, there a no files in storage/logs :(. And i'm sure try all your solution recommended. But the problem has not been resolved :(

Comment: @Ben i have no problems without mcrypt extension installed. 5.1. interesting why... especially if it is defined in official documentation as "must be"

Comment: Anything in apache's log file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you create the .env file and set your APP_KEY? Also, you can enable debuging by adding `APP_DEBUG=true` to your .env file.

Comment: Look at this discussion and tell me if it solved your problem. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blank-screen-when-thrown-into-server

Comment: Thank you, but my problem is persist :( I was updated inforcation in question

Comment: This is really strange to get `UnexpectedValueException` if you do nothing. Is-it a clean install of Laravel?